# Eclipse says I have a compilation error when I don't - How to fix?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I'm writing a java project and suddenly, out of nowhere eclipse is reporting that I have a problem with my code. It's specific to one file, but others are failing as well as they use a couple functions from the class in question, which they can't seem to find, the functions that is. I've tried almost everything I can think of to make this error go away.

- Refreshing project
- Clean project
- Remove project and re-import
- Removing file, make a new, paste content
- Removed errors and cleaned project

To be specific the first error is:

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

Just to illustrate, here's the code:

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import model.HolderCompany;
import model.Row;
import viewmodel.App;

public class PanelMain extends JPanel {

    private PanelTable table;
    private DataDialog editDialog;
    private DataDialog addDialog;
    private ManageCompaniesDialog mcDialog;
    private PanelConsole consolePane;
    private JFrame frame;
    private ArrayList<Row> data;
    private ArrayList<HolderCompany> companies;

    private static String[] labelHeaders = {
        "ID",
        "Deployment Date",
        "IMEI",
        "Name",
        "Model",
        "Software Version",
        "A51 Device",
        "Holder Company",
        "Company E-mail",
        "Company Phone"
    }; //Here is the so called Syntax Error

    public PanelMain(){
        frame = new JFrame("Mobile Sensor Manager");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        consolePane = new PanelConsole();

        //Button Pane
        JButton addRow = new JButton("Add Row");
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addDialog = openDialog("Add Row");
                //Wait for return here
                Object[] data = addDialog.getData();
                if(data != null){
                    table.addRowToTable(data);
                    consolePane.write("Added row: " + table.dataToString(data), null);
                }
            }
        });

        JButton editRow = new JButton("Edit Row");
        editRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int index = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(index == -1){
                    //Write error message
                    consolePane.write("No row is selected!", null);
                } else {
                    Object[] d1 = table.getData(index);
                    editDialog = openDialog("Edit Row", data);
                    Row data =     App.getSharedResources().getData().get(index); 
                    editDialog = openDialog("Edit Row", data);
                    //Wait for return here
                    Object[] newData = editDialog.getData();
                    Row newRow = editDialog.getRow();
                    if(newData != null){
                        table.changeRowInTable(index, newData);
                        App.getSharedResources().changeRow(index, newRow);
                        consolePane.write("Changed row " + index + " to " + table.dataToString(newData), null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        JButton deleteRow = new JButton("Delete Row");
        deleteRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int index = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(index == -1){
                    //Write error message
                    consolePane.write("No row is selected!", null);
                } else {
                    consolePane.write("Removed row: " + table.tableIndexToString(index), null);
                    table.deleteRowFromTable(index);
                    App.getSharedResources().removeRow(index);
                }
            }
        });

        JButton manageCompanies = new JButton("Manage Companies");
        manageCompanies.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mcDialog = openDialog();
            }
        });

        JButton clearDB = new JButton("Clear Database");
        JButton deleteDB = new JButton("Delete Database");

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        TitledBorder buttonBorder = new TitledBorder("Buttons");
        buttonPane.setBorder(buttonBorder);

        buttonPane.add(addRow);
        buttonPane.add(editRow);
        buttonPane.add(deleteRow);
        buttonPane.add(new JSeparator());
        buttonPane.add(manageCompanies);
        buttonPane.add(new JSeparator());
        buttonPane.add(clearDB);
        buttonPane.add(deleteDB);

        //Table Pane
        table = new PanelTable();

        JPanel tablePane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        TitledBorder dbContentBorder = new TitledBorder("Database Content");
        tablePane.setBorder(dbContentBorder);
        tablePane.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pane.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        pane.add(tablePane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(consolePane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public DataDialog openDialog(String name){
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        return new DataDialog(win, new DataTemplate(), name);
    }

    public DataDialog openDialog(String name, Object[] data){
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        return new DataDialog(win, new DataTemplate(), name, data);
    }

    public DataDialog openDialog(String name, Row data){
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        return new DataDialog(win, new DataTemplate(), name, data);
    }

    public ManageCompaniesDialog openDialog() {
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        return new ManageCompaniesDialog(win, new     ManageCompaniesTemplate(companies));
    }

    public void injectCompanies(ArrayList<HolderCompany> companies) {
        this.companies = companies;
    }

    public void injectData(ArrayList<Row> data) {
        this.data = data;
        table.injectDataToTable(data);
    }

    public void addMainToFrame(PanelMain main) {
        frame.add(main);
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI(){
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static String[] getHeaders() {
        return labelHeaders;
    }
}
```

## EDIT

Is it just me or does anyone else get this error?

Any suggestions on how to fix it are welcome!

Comment: Could you specify *line number *

Comment: @MehrajMalik: More usefully, he's commented the line in the code.

Comment: I posted a comment in the code on where the error is appearing. But it is in line 42

Comment: Is it some Eclipse workspace metadata problem? What happens if you create a new workspace and import the project?

Comment: Same thing. I just created a completely new workspace and imported the project and I still get the error.

Comment: What happens if you strip the whole class, except the static array declaration?

Comment: If I strip the entire class except for the FieldDeclarations it compiles just fine. I managed to get the file compiling if I remove the content from the constructor. The constructor is defined, but it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I finally managed to fix the error.

As mentioned in the comments in the top post I could get it to compile if I cleared the constructor. Once I got it to compile I slowly copy pasted the code line by line into my project. I left out the ActionListeners and it compiled just fine. After this I slowly imported the ActionListener methods one by one and I found a line that resulted in the error. It was the line:

```
App.getSharedResources().changeRow(index, newRow); //line 106
```

This method was not yet implemented and it gave me that as an error after the above explained process. I could create the method and the rest of my code compiles as intended now. This was a really weird error.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. (BTW: consider accepting your own answer to mark that it solves the problem described).

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced similar issue sometime in past, could you please try to delete the error from 'Problems' view and perform a clean project afterwards, and see if it disappears.

If it does not help try: looking into the .log file created by eclipse in your workspace directory. That may hold a clue how to fix this.

Comment: I had tried this already. And it didn't work. I did however fix my problem as set as the answer. Thanks for input however ;)